# Каково значение оборота "ушки на макушке"?

Tags: фразеология

**Ушки на макушке —** (Внимательно прислушиваться, быть настороже.) Ср. У наших ушки на макушке! Чуть утро осветило пушки И леса синие опушки Французы тут как тут. М.Ю. Лермонтов. Бородино.  **Большой толково-фразеологический словарь**

Но есть мнение, что ***ушки на макушке*** бывают не только от настороженности, но и от радости, и фразеологизм этот переосмыслен со временем.

И почему всё-таки были "ушки на макушке" у наших солдат в стихотворении Лермонтова "Бородино"? Может быть, о**т радости, что отступление окончено и наконец предстоит решающая битва?**

Какой вариант лучше согласуется с текстом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В нашем современном языковом сознании это выражение — ушки на макушке, держать ушки на макушке — означает «быть начеку, быть внимательным и готовым к чему-либо непредвиденному или неожиданному».

Все мы помним строки М. Ю. Лермонтова из стихотворения «Бородино»:

*У наших ушки на макушке!*

*Чуть утро осветило пушки*

*И леса синие верхушки —*

*Французы тут как тут.*

Можно привести и другие примеры на употребление этого выражения в русской литературе. И все их мы понимаем именно так: «быть начеку». Однако известный советский языковед В. И. Чернышев относил это выражение к числу таких речевых оборотов, которые были переосмыслены на протяжении своей долгой жизни в языке.

Сейчас, действительно, держать ушки на макушке означает «быть особенно внимательным». Так истолковано это выражение уже более ста лет назад и в знаменитом Словаре В. И. Даля. Но ***в народном языке оно значит или по крайней мере значило также «испытывать большую радость»***.

В подтверждение этому В. И. Чернышев приводил пример из романа И. А. Гончарова «Обыкновенная история». Там есть такие строки: «Я уже с матерью за кофеем разговорилась, да шутя и забросила словечко: **у ней, кажется, и ушки на макушке от радости**». **В. И. Чернышев считал, что и в лермонтовском стихотворении «Бородино» строка «У наших ушки на макушке!» означает именно выражение радости, радости воинов перед предстоящей битвой.** И действительно, если взять предшествующие строки стихотворения, то в них сначала выражена горечь по поводу длительного отступления русской армии перед захватчиком:

*Мы долго молча отступали,*

*Досадно было, боя ждали,*

*Ворчали старики...*

А следующая строфа содержит полную смену настроения:

*И вот нашли большое поле:*

*Есть разгуляться где на воле!*

*Построили редут.*

*У наших ушки на макушке!*

Действительно, это можно понять скорее как солдатскую радость после долгого отступления и накануне решающей битвы.

Такое толкование вполне согласуется с общим содержанием стихотворения. А переосмысление фразеологизмов в истории языка — явление довольно распространенное.

---

**[источник](http://www.winstein.org/publ/8-1-0-195)**

Comment: Спасибо большое! Всё сразу стало  понятно. И пользуясь случаем, поздравляю Вас с Новым годом и Рождеством. Приходите почаще, нам очень не хватает Ваших  интересных ответов и Вашего юмора, а то здесь все очень серьезные.

Comment: Очень интересно! Хочется добавить: когда человек широко улыбается, его "ушки" под влиянием радостной улыбки чуть-чуть как будто приподнимаются.  Может быть, поэтому выражение "ушки на макушке"   означает радоваться, веселиться?

Comment: Sharon, и Вас с Новым годом и только что минувшим Рождеством, а что до моего юмора, то просят сурьёзные люди: не раскачивайте сайт! ))) Катюша, думаю, Вы правы с взъезжанием ушек! )))

Comment: А под влиянием чего произошло переосмысление фразеологизма?

Comment: Не могу знать, я процитировала мини-очерк с указанием источника.

Comment: Я всегда думал, что “ушки на макушке” — это настороженная поза у кошек и собак (уши подняты).

Comment: К такому толкованию и взывает первый абзац процитированного.